# How to build libXrender

Tags: linux, unix, build, x11

I get an error when configuring the libXrender package

```
checking for RENDER... configure: error: Package requirements (x11 renderproto >= 0.9) were not met:

No package 'x11' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables RENDER_CFLAGS
and RENDER_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

my configure is

```
./configure --prefix=/tmp/instigate-software/gnu_system/3.2/x86_64/
```

but when I write echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH I get

```
/tmp/instigate-software/gnu_system/3.2/x86_64/lib/pkgconfig
```

this is what is contained in the pkgconfig folder

```
ls /tmp/instigate-software/gnu_system/3.2/x86_64/lib/pkgconfig/

bigreqsproto.pc    freetype2.pc   libpng16.pc    mpfr.pc           recordproto.pc     videoproto.pc     xcb-proto.pc        xcb-sync.pc      xcb-xv.pc
binutils.pc        gettext.pc     libpng.pc      ncurses.pc        renderproto.pc     xau.pc            xcb-randr.pc        xcb-xevie.pc     xcmiscproto.pc
bison.pc           glproto.pc     libtiff-4.pc   pciaccess.pc      resourceproto.pc   xcb-composite.pc  xcb-record.pc       xcb-xf86dri.pc   xdmcp.pc
compositeproto.pc  gmp.pc         libxcb.pc      pixman-1.pc       scrnsaverproto.pc  xcb-damage.pc     xcb-render.pc       xcb-xfixes.pc    xextproto.pc
damageproto.pc     ice.pc         libXdmcp.pc    pthread-stubs.pc  sigc++-2.0.pc      xcb-dpms.pc       xcb-res.pc          xcb-xinerama.pc  xf86driproto.pc
expat.pc           inputproto.pc  libxml-2.0.pc  python-2.7.pc     sm.pc              xcb-dri2.pc       xcb-screensaver.pc  xcb-xprint.pc    xineramaproto.pc
fixesproto.pc      kbproto.pc     libxslt.pc     python.pc         stdc++.pc          xcb-glx.pc        xcb-shape.pc        xcb-xtest.pc     xproto.pc
fontsproto.pc      libexslt.pc    m4.pc          randrproto.pc     tiff.pc            xcb.pc            xcb-shm.pc          xcb-xvmc.pc      zlib.pc
```

and this is what is contained in the renderproto.pc file

```
prefix=/tmp/instigate-software/gnu_system/3.2/x86_64
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: RenderProto
Description: Render extension headers
Version: 0.11
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

from what can it be ?